# Is it possible to merge several loose parts into a mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I am using Blender version 2.92.0. I am trying to edit meshes to form facials. To do this, I have to make sure my model's face mesh has no loose parts (All of my models do not have face/mouth bones).

Here is an example of what I need. The colors represent the loose parts. This is one I have done (The mouth is originally closed, but I opened it.)
[image]

But some of my models are like this:
[image]

It shows that every single vertex is a loose part, and I do not want that.

Is there a way that I can merge all the loose parts that I want into a single piece? Note that my second model's face is A SINGLE MESH with a bunch of loose parts. I want it to look like the face of the first model.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try merging by distance with all selected?

Comment: I think I did. However, please show me a example about what you mean.

Comment: select all and press M > Merge by Distance

Answer (score 1):

Enter edit mode. Press "1" (not the one on the numpad, the regular number 1, to enter filter edit mode selection: vertices), Press "A" to select all vertices. Press F3 and search "merge by distance". Use 0.0002 and see if that works.
Cheers.

Comment: Don't forget that before the merging of vertices takes place, the various loose parts must all be joined into one mesh object by being all selected at once and then pressing Ctrl j.