# How do I animate a rigid body with an animation?

Tags: animation, mesh, bones, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I am trying to do an animation. I have an animated fish that bends its body for a few seconds and then flopping rigorously (like real fish when it is out of the water.)

I want to make the fish fall from a great height while bending its body due to force. Then when it hits the ground, it flops around.

I tried using rigid body physics for this. However, my fish stays in the same place while moving.

It is obvious that I can just animate the fish falling. But it will look unrealistic.

I want my fish fall to the ground while playing the animation from the very first second. I do not want to use Blender Game Engine because I am making a animation story, not a game.

Comment: How have you animated the fish? With an armature or shapekeys? Have you checked the *Animated* checkbox in the *Rigid Body* settings? It must be UNchecked to make the object fall and controlled by the rigid physics

Comment: To use physics you need to set the fish to be an active rigid body and the ground to be a passive one.  You'll have to play with weights and springiness to get it to bound around.  The deformation is harder.  You'll need force fields to generate the bending as the fish falls -- by simulating air pressure.  You'll also need collision physics to keep the fish from falling through the ground.  You may find animating easier in the long rung.

Comment: Reply Blunder: I used armature. Oh, I did check the Animated box. Now I have unchecked it, it is finally working! Thanks a lot. However, maybe I should try Marty Fouts idea.

Comment: By the way, could you help me solve this problem here? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/233734/is-it-possible-to-merge-several-loose-parts-into-a-mesh